# How to get all the different values from elements that are members of the same class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="www.google.com" value="1000" class="abc">Link1</a>
<a href="www.google.com" value="1001" class="abc">Link2</a>
<a href="www.google.com" value="1002" class="abc">Link3</a>
<a href="www.google.com" value="1003" class="abc">Link4</a>
<a href="www.google.com" value="1004" class="abc">Link5</a>
<a href="www.google.com" value="1005" class="abc">Link6</a>
<a href="www.google.com" value="1006" class="abc">Link7</a>
<a href="www.google.com" value="1007" class="abc">Link8</a>
```

I am having 7 link on the UI.

i want all the links values in an array like

```
array_v = [1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007]
```

where class is same for all the links.....

Is there any way that we can get all values of same css class by jquery or javascript...

i tried with

```
document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
```

but i am getting output like this :

```
HTMLCollection[a.abc #, a.abc #, a.abc #, a.abc #, a.abc #, a.abc #, a.abc #]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
var array_v  = [];

$(".abc").each(function(i, e){
    array_v[i] = $(this).attr("value");
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f1oLxevb/8/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var array_v = [].map.call(document.getElementsByClassName('abc'), function(elem) {
  return elem.getAttribute("value");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.map` in jquery

```
var res = $("a.abc").map(function(val, i) {

        return $(this).val();

}).get();
```